# How to Automatic change categories in auction site (like : Upcoming auction , Current Auction And Past Auction)?

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I want automatic change categories by date according upcoming, past and current. Automatically upcoming categories change in current at same date that it will realised. On the other hand current categories automatically change or shift in past categories.

Comment: You can use postexpirator plugin, to add, replace or delete categories on given dates.

Answer (score 0):

you can use orderby attribute while getting category. 
`'orderby'    => 'date', 
    'order'      => 'DESC',`